# Go, Mongo problems

Tags: mongodb, go

I am new using Go, but I would like to know if there is a problem if I add new attributes to a Collection in Mongo, once my model is defined in Go. Form example

I defined in Go this Model:

```
type material struct {
    ID               string    `bson:"_id" json:"_id"`
    Name             string    `bson:"name" json:"name"`
    Entity         string    `bson:"entity" json:"entity"`

}
```

and I create new attributes on Material Collection for example:

Collection Material

All Attributes: ID, Name, Entity,Country(NEW ONE)

Is it necessary to update the model knowing that I will not use that attribute for the project?

Comment: When you read from the db, the struct with the missing field will simply lose that field. But if you replace records using this struct, you will overwrite the record with a copy that doesn't have the new field.